# tsqlt and dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, tsqlt

I am trying to test a sproc which uses dynamic sql like this:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- create @Sql

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
,N'@NumberOfRollingMonths INT, @FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME'
,@NumberOfRollingMonths = @NumberOfRollingMonths
,@FromDate = @FromDate
,@ToDate = @ToDate
```

Whatever I do, I do not get the the test to pass. I am using

```
EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable
```

to fake the underlying database's data. Is it a known fact that tsqlt does not work with dynamic sql?

PS:

Some more code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TestDetails', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE TestDetails

CREATE TABLE TestDetails
(
    Year INT,
    Period INT,
    HOURS INT 
)
INSERT INTO TestDetails (Year, Period, HOURS) 
    SELECT 2004, 1, 10000 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2004, 2, 100

IF OBJECT_ID('TestMonthsAndYears', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE TestMonthsAndYears

CREATE TABLE TestMonthsAndYears
(
    Id INT not null identity(1,1) primary KEY,
    TheMonth INT NOT NULL,
    TheYear INT NOT NULL,
    [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL 
)

DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME
SET @FromDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @ToDate = '2200-01-01 00:00:00.000'

INSERT INTO TestMonthsAndYears 
SELECT 
    TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @FromDate, @ToDate) + 1) 
    [TheMonth] = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, number, @FromDate)),
    [TheYear]  = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, number, @FromDate)),
    [Date]  = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, number, @FromDate)), 0)
FROM [master].dbo.spt_values 
WHERE [type] = N'P'

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys . objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'ToBeRemoved' )
DROP PROCEDURE ToBeRemoved
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ToBeRemoved]
    @FromDate DATETIME,
    @ToDate DATETIME,
    @NumberOfRollingMonths INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SumSql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SumSql = N''
    IF(@NumberOfRollingMonths > 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @NumberOfRollingMonths = @NumberOfRollingMonths * -1;
        END

    SET @SumSql = @SumSql + N' SUM(CAST(D.HOURS AS FLOAT)) '

    SET @Sql = N'
    ;WITH SparseValues AS
    (
        SELECT 
            CAST(CAST(D.YEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT(''0'' + CAST(D.Period AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ''01'' AS SMALLDATETIME) AS MonthYear,
            ' + @SumSql + ' AS Value
        FROM TestDetails D
        GROUP BY CAST(CAST(D.YEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT(''0'' + CAST(D.Period AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ''01'' AS SMALLDATETIME) 
    )
    ,CompleteValues AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            MY.[Date], 
            ISNULL(Value,0) AS Value
        FROM TestMonthsAndYears MY
        LEFT JOIN SparseValues SparseValues ON MY.[Date] = SparseValues.MonthYear
        WHERE MY.Date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
    )
    SELECT 
        S1.[Date], 
        AVG(S2.Value) AS MovingAverage
    FROM CompleteValues AS S1, CompleteValues AS S2
    WHERE S2.[Date] > DATEADD(m, @NumberOfRollingMonths,S1.[Date]) AND S2.[Date] <= S1.[Date]
    GROUP BY S1.[Date] order by date'

    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
        ,N'@NumberOfRollingMonths INT, @FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME'
        ,@NumberOfRollingMonths = @NumberOfRollingMonths
        ,@FromDate = @FromDate
        ,@ToDate = @ToDate
END


EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass 'MyTestClass';
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [MyTestClass].[test very good test]
AS
BEGIN
    -- arrange 
    IF OBJECT_ID('Expected') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Expected;
    IF OBJECT_ID('Actual') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Actual;

    EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable 'dbo', 'TestDetails';
    INSERT INTO dbo.TestDetails (Year, period, [HOURS]) 
        SELECT 2004, 1, 30 UNION ALL
        SELECT 2004, 2, 10

    CREATE TABLE Expected(Date DATETIME, MovingAverage float)
    CREATE TABLE Actual(Date DATETIME, MovingAverage float)
    INSERT INTO Expected (Date, MovingAverage) 
        SELECT '2004-01-01 00:00:00.000', 30 UNION ALL
        SELECT '2004-02-01 00:00:00.000', 10

    -- act
    DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME SET @FromDate = '2004-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME SET @ToDate = '2004-02-01 00:00:00.000'
    DECLARE @NumberOfRollingMonths INT SET @NumberOfRollingMonths = -1

    INSERT INTO Actual
    EXEC ToBeRemoved @FromDate, @ToDate, @NumberOfRollingMonths

    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable 'Expected', 'Actual', 'Actual result table not equal to expected result table.';
END
```

Comment: include the dynamic SQL statement you are using, and specify what error you are getting.

Comment: I have not used tsqlt, but depending on the outcome here, you might want to take a look at http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/ . It is a wonderful testing tool that requires no additional code/schema in the DB.

Comment: T-SQL certainly processes dynamic SQL.  Instead of posting `-- create @Sql` you should show us the actual code.

Comment: ok thanks. will do tomorrow.

Comment: @Max I was talking about tsqlt not tsql!

Comment: @charles i am not getting any error. i am inserting some data into a db table using tsqlt.faketable. the data is accessesd via a sproc with dynamic sql. thi does not produce the expected results (compared via tsqlt table compare). when i replace the dynamic sql with hard coded one the test passes as expected (actual = expected).the sproc works fine during integration manual tests btw!

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the test case and the dynamic sql which you are testing? That way we have a chance of seeing what the problem might be. Dynamic SQL does work with tSQLt (as you can see in @DaveGreen's answer). However, there might be something about your particular dynamic SQL, or your test case that might be causing the issue.

Comment: Ok thanks. I understand now that dynamic tsql works with tsqlt. Thanks for that. I added some adapted code that describes my situation. Strangely enough this test passes (any comments to improve it would be very much appreciated). Anyway, there must be something else wrong at my end, so I will accept DaveGreen's answer as it proofs nicely that dynamic sql should not be a problem as such. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Hi @csetzkorn, it would be helpful to see what the result of AssertEqualsTable is producing. Can you show that? Also, just to debug things, can you take the line in your test procedure "INSERT INTO Actual ... EXEC ToBeRemoved ..." and just execute "EXEC ToBeRemoved...". Then re-run your test case. That way you can see the results that come from calling the ToBeRemoved procedure. That would help us debug your situation.

Comment: @dennislloydjr everything is sorted (btw the above code can be run in your environment too and is working). The problem was that I did not include a column used in the actual sproc into the fake table.

Comment: @csetzkorn - glad you figured it out. It does look strange in your test case that you are not also faking the other tables. Normally, you will want to fake all tables that your procedure uses so that your test case has control of the data.

Comment: @dennislloydjr just digested your comment. Are you, for example, refering to TestMonthsAndYears?

Comment: @csetzkorn - yes, TestMonthsAndYears and CompleteValues

Comment: @dennislloydjr Thanks for your comments. Just curious, why do I have to add data to CompleteValues - as it is a cte within the sproc?

Comment: @csetzkorn - because clearly I didn't read your code closely enough ;-)  It looks like TestMonthAndYears may also be a read-only-ish lookup table and be deployed from the get-go with months and years. Therefore, I might not fake that either.

Comment: @dennislloydjr thanks. OK so what needs to be faked? My current understanding (after your comments) is that I assume that the whole db is empty during the test and I have to fake all tables involved in the test. This does not include cte-s of course but TestMonthsAndYears is a 'proper' db table so needs to be faked imho?!

Comment: @csetzkom In practice, if I am testing a stored procedure, I normally fake all tables that would be called. I make no presumption that the database is empty or not. However, I write and execute my unit tests in a development database (never run tSQLt tests in production). I think there is room for debate about faking a table that always contains a hard-coded set of values that have been setup during deployment. CTEs cannot be faked since they are created on the fly during the execution of the code being tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented, Dynamic SQL does work with tSQLt. Without the code / test with which you are experiencing issues, it's difficult to be definitive as to where your problem might lie.

To help you along, and help restore your confidence in tSQLt, here's an example of a SP using dynamic SQL, and a test that calls it, and fake table, to unit test the procedure:

```
USE tSQLt_Example
GO
--Example table in which we will manipulate data
CREATE TABLE dbo.DynamicDemo (a INT)
GO
INSERT dbo.DynamicDemo (a) VALUES (5) -- This value will be removed by FakeTable
GO
--Example proc which uses Dynamic SQL
CREATE PROC dbo.DynamicAdd (@NoToAdd int) as
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @s = 'update dbo.DynamicDemo set a=a+@NoToAdd'
EXEC sp_executesql @s,N'@NoToAdd int',@NoToAdd = @NoToAdd
GO
--create tSQLt class
exec tSQLt.NewTestClass @ClassName = N'DynamicTest' -- nvarchar(max)
GO
--Create test on proc which uses dynamic SQL
CREATE PROC DynamicTest.[test dynamic sql]
as
--Assemble
EXEC tSQLt.faketable 'dbo.DynamicDemo'
SELECT TOP 0 * into DynamicTest.Expected FROM dbo.DynamicDemo
INSERT dbo.DynamicDemo (a) VALUES (4) --Start position
INSERT DynamicTest.Expected (a) VALUES (7) -- Expected end position
--Act
EXEC dbo.DynamicAdd 3 --call proc under test
--Assert
EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable @Actual='dbo.DynamicDemo', @Expected = 'DynamicTest.Expected'
GO
--Run Tests
EXEC tSQLt.Run 'DynamicTest'
GO
--Clearup
DROP TABLE dbo.dynamicDemo
DROP PROC dbo.DynamicAdd
```

This simple example should help to reassure you that tSQLt itself is capable of using dynamic SQL just fine - perhaps there is another dependency which is causing you issues? If (as others have said) you can post a (runable) example of your problem we can help you work out what is causing you this pain.

Comment: thank you for the answer but if there are million records in dbo.DynamicDemo then whats the best way to go forward as it will forever to run the test

Comment: The call to faketable isolates from the underlying table, so the rows in it that the test sees are only those inserted after the faketable statement.